# Image file with no file extension is now a strange code to me

Tags: image, file, jpeg

I have some unreadable image files that have no file extension.

I have passed them to my macbook(os x 10.9.1) from my iPhone(iOS 7) using disk aid 6.

I have tried to just add .jpg and .png back to the end of them but to of no avail.

When i open them in text editor i am seeing a long string of code with symbols and letters.

I need help identifying this code and I am wondering is there any way possible to return the script to its original image or .jpg or can i get any of the information that it once held?

This is a sample of this code:

```
¸^NjÛ®p‰9πK∂]™¨oêkØ2
é8í"YXØ∆–„±�Üäé∑≠∂7_Ó˝’ï#Oq ØcÁ†5p°ŒÎ£…ö&Å∆^Î'4O◊y{6T_œxû+Â´EñÇÆ!º%Ã†y; seÊ›À[®°^ﬁ9w%∂¯œhäÏƒ‹ Ÿ⁄€¨’hÂÇò∏Ñ}e»¶µMB    §Ë{1é–Ï≥OÌ\vNÅb˛ÎœVKüøœ≥sb ˜vÛ[<z¨à™|≠ˆ®1C≤Ãgae™ÿ¶°±«j-+ñ¸ëº∫Ï≈+3µ‚˛~ËAÊ\ûóµá#æ˙)ˆ/hUÈΩÃQS\Êî(TÃ}´h«ˇLlç˝WyBﬂ\ıîÊy«.¿àOò< ¡@˘Á¥’_…∏>ï◊€˜•7Â÷rŸí‹ºß≥rá$zØ˛ıáïLÛ‚8‰<ŒÓ�„‡Jg—7\[’ÙÂ©0�ô‚∫˘„oÒ-z’,PÙ≠\7£j<,W∫>¬‰:‘
ﬂ)U[ú˜òÕÖF3y=ç[.8æCãﬁú∞[ûc_i¯á€!˛ñ/‰⁄∆~†‘ÂÚ{Ôw¢TíÖèD®c¡√-wÍ_Ô�®ï2‘Ÿp�rﬂ∏ô2Vï∫dû„æê§;=zúeÒêˆßM   €÷•‚qŸA·ƒ2�˝Â˝UΩÎ�õMUe*˚Ã.d∫ßêó€ç√dÂπm9ÃÎΩK≥ë¶�ÚÌÁ.d
åƒﬂ√ºÌù∆…r\IoHkOZﬂ2≈ÃK©+bc+«ÃÆ∂-Û,≤ûπCxßêød˘–J™¥[ÀÀR”&·�∆}ë°kÚ_<>ØcBà·´-Ç—Úˇ`‡ó›b$ózDn˙”¯QŸ ?ËÀ«∆˝vK(/·Ó3Ü¯Ãk¨£®∂©€˛œâπã0±ß;—õˆ¡Wåõ≤ã_J˘·‚∑:Kc ﬁÒ`Åı5¯u9Ê∞€K¢◊lûcG∏3üF∑ößño6M”ó®+M∞â∫Êî˝ÃµYÇ–Ωôp éf'W‚a[hÔ`ï6VÊ&$∏€!õÊ°x¶)j¶-8Vñ€@%üP9q˚AHÈ¡Îú€€äJ·Fçˆ:çê2ø¡Sv‹69}x%éÊ}=≤…—ñíòÙ†EQŸãh¿7ísá±D≥∂K    …DÃÚ��–^;
lÙÜÚ8!döt‰:√…Í£E∆¬î±≥p
¯^«≈Ü%ND¶y≠3]‡hæ¿3_‹öŸÿ6•PÂ÷q0’¨p2ùŸ4Æg[ŒAF˛¥¶{ÍﬂËP¡„ΩÜJK®pˆj¡¶n'I˚ïÆ.ÁF⁄Ä∫ºU§—äïàﬂ¥Mkúa-&;8!q§A
ıà|ròªÖ–$y¶G?ˇèåA?·ïK∑,"|πû˛)∞"¨,mLT-j[ÖPoL◊vioµ≠ œ,È"ˇ2{I·«≈˜Ã
```

This is just a very small portion of the text, could someone please help me?

Comment: eh, do a hexdump of the first part. i.e `hexdump -C file | sed '10q'` or similar and update your question with that

Comment: so sorry my friend i do not know how to do any of this but i was hoping if i could identify the script maybe i could learn how to retrieve the images again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run Linux, use the "file" command like this:

```
file somefile
```

and it will tell you what type the file is.

Or use the "od" command like this to see the first few bytes in hex:

```
od -xc somefile | more
```

then you may get some insight.

Comment: sorry i don't run linux, i actually do not program at all so this is new to me

Comment: If they are from your iPhone, they may well be PNG files. Try adding ".png" to their names.

Comment: @user3279894 - in order to help you we need the hexdump. Can you perhaps upload the file somewhere? See this question for doing a hexdump in windows http://superuser.com/questions/468456/how-can-i-view-the-binary-contents-of-a-file-natively-in-windows-7-is-it-possi

Comment: A png-file always start with these bytes `137 80 78 71 13 10 26 10`

Comment: I am running os x 10.9.1 and have also tried to add a .png file extension any time i try to open the file with a file extension I am getting a error message that the file can not be opened or is damaged?

Comment: If you are running OSX, you can use the "file" command I suggested!!! Save the file in your login directory. Start a Terminal. Type "file yourfilename" then hit Enter key

Comment: You start Terminal by pressing "cmd + spacebar" at the same time and typing "Term" and hitting "Enter"

Comment: ok thanks i got the terminal open but how do i save the file to my login directory I'm so sorry i am brand new to this

Comment: Start the Finder, drag a file from wherever it is to the folder with a little house on it (your home folder)

Comment: The Finder should be in the dock at the bottom of your screen. It is 2 different shades of blue and looks like a smiley face.

Comment: Have you got it worked out now? If so, and my answer helped, please accept it so I get a lovely big green tick. If not, please say what you are stuck on now, and maybe someone will be able to help you further. You are welcome to Email me a file and I will have a look at it for you - mark at thesetchells dot com

Comment: mark I'm sorry i just got back to my screen now, i got the file command done and it says filename: data

Answer (score 0):

Try opening your image file with a program that can handle many image types ([GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/), Photoshop, etc.), maybe it will auto-detect your image's type.

You can also use online services like: http://www.converthub.com/

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like they are not JPEG files. Opening a JPEG file in a text editor should result in JFIF in the first few bytes. Did you get these from and FTP site? they may have been downloaded as ASCII and not binary in which case you will not be able to recover them.
Most image files have these identifying bytes.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_File_Interchange_Format#File_format_structure

Comment: thanks but no I did not get them from a site, I am trying to retrieve images from my iPhone which have no file extension at all. so when i open them they are coming up in my text editor like this.

Comment: Probably worth editing your question to make that clear,. What application on the IPhone is generating the images? Are you transferring them wired via Itunes?

Comment: thanks i will do that now i am transferring them from my iPhone with disk aid 6 from a self destruct photo app